# Visual Studio Call stack window what does + ... bytes mean?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, callstack

I've noticed that in Visual Studio Call stack window, after
... Line xx for some lines there is something like **+ 0x1e bytes** added in the end.

I tried googling about that, but did not find anything that would explain how should I interpret that information.

Can anyone explain what it means and what it is for in Call stack?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A single line of source code is typically compiled to a set of MSIL instructions. Debugging information attaches the line number to the first instruction that  was created by a source line. All the other instructions are then represented by the source line + an offset, given in bytes.

Comment: Ok, where could I get some practical use from this debug information?

Comment: @Prokurors Rigth click the debug information you could go to view source code and disassembly.

Comment: @Prokurors, You could get enough helpful information from Hans Passant suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670178/how-to-understand-the-call-stack-of-visual-studio and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893945/call-stack-byte-offset